# Are there any webforum projects for ASP and IIS like there is for PHP and Apache?

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, iis

I wonder if anything similar exists. If it does, I can't find it. Most webforums are written completely in PHP and are designed to run on Apache these days.

Don't start any software argument here please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Comparison of Internet forum software (ASP) on WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software_%28ASP%29) is a good list :)